# Unable to ignore index.php from application URL developed using codeigniter on IIS

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, iis, web-config

I have an application developed in codeigniter and deployed in IIS Windows shared hosting plesk control panel.
When I navigate to the website it doesn't remove the `index.php` from the URL and page is not rendered correctly.

- **Actual url** : `www.example.com/index.php/auth`
- **Expected url**: `www.example.com/auth`

Note: when I manually type Actual URL it redirects the page properly to Expected URL. But this is not true when
I type only `www.example.com`, it redirects user to Actual URL i.e.

Following is the `.htaccess` file configuration and its relevant configuration I set up in IIS.

#### .htaccess

```sh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

#### Web.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This directory structure is on shared windows hosting machine.

```
--- application
    assets
    install
    system
    vendor
    .htaccess
    index.php
    web.config
```

Comment: If you are using IIS, how is that .htaccess relevant?   Is that an example you found somewhere that you want to emulate?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. its not relevant in IIS. But, this code was previously deployed on the apache server on linux machine. I have moved my hosting from linux to windows. and created the equivalent web.config file from htaccess file. The purpose  of putting htaccess file here is to verify that the URL rewrite rules are set correctly in web.config file on IIS server

Comment: If you don’t want index.php to appear in your url, then the rewrite url you set in iis should not include index.php, about how to translate .htaccess Content to IIS web.config you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig).

Answer (score 0):

In `app/config/config.php`

You have to overwrite

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

It will ignore `index.php` from application

Comment: config.php already has the settings you mentioned. Still its not working.